# php boolean help

Tags: php, boolean

I seem to have a small problem, in the code below $a_trip is always true, even if $trip!= $admin_trip. Any idea why?

```
if($trip == $admin_trip)
$a_trip = true;


if($a_trip == true)
$trip = ("~::##Admin##::~");
```

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, strings and numbers other than zero will evaluate as true. Make sure that $a_trip is false or empty, or use the equality operator that evaluates type:

```
if($a_trip === true)
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP's normal equality is very lax, and considers many values to be the same even when types are different.

Answer (score 0):

Beat me to it. === means 'identical'.

Check this out.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Also a sidenote, you should use **{ }** in your if statements. You'll thank yourself later when debugging. It's easier to read.