# any difference between if ('1') and if ('true')?

Tags: php, if-statement

I read a string from a config file:

```
boolean = true
```

Although in php $config["boolean"]  => String(1) "1"

is there any difference?

Comment: Related/duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044348/php-understanding-string-type-juggling

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php boolean help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485506/php-boolean-help)

Comment: Why do people spend that much time searching for a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes difference exists...

In this case

> if ('1') and if ('true')

'1' first be converted to true, then executed... But result has been always same...

Of course, exist small speed difference(then need concerted types it's take a little bit more time to do that)... But it's like always - nobody cares :-D

Good to know:

```
if ( 1 == true) { } // returns true
if ( 1 === true) { } // returns false
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: it might be good to expand as to why 1== sure and 1=== true are different, but I've upvoted the answer as the two matrix are really good - I wish I'd had them when I started out!